# How to debug noflo-nodejs

Tags: node-inspector, noflo

How do I start noflo-nodejs with debugging enabled so that I can debug using node-inspector?

I've tried adding the `--debug-brk` option when calling `noflo-nodejs.cmd`

I've also tried calling `node "node_modules\noflo-nodejs\bin\noflo-nodejs" --debug-brk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First what you can do:
Update Node Inspector to latest version (`npm update node-inspector`).

Use `node-debug node_modules\noflo-nodejs\bin\noflo-nodejs`

Or `node-debug node_modules\noflo-nodejs`

`node-debug` is a new command of node-inspector. It opens debugging process in debug mode (same as `--debug-brk`) and opens debugger page in chrome (if it is your default browser).

If `node-debug` is not helpful, try:

Check that your port `5858` is free.

Put in first terminal `node node_modules\noflo-nodejs\bin\noflo-nodejs`

Put in second terminal `node-inspector`

Open in chrome `http://127.0.0.1/debug`

If this not works welcome to [node-inspector/issues](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues?state=open)